# Getting count for Facebook shares with json_decode

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, json

I'm trying to get the count for `Facebook` shares with this function :

```
<?php

function get_likes($url) {
$json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
return intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
}

echo get_likes("http://facebook.com");

?>
```

Sometimes, it's working (I get the good count), but sometimes I get zero share.
I didn't manage to identify the reason why (and I tried with tens URL from various websites). Moreover, when I go to this URL `http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://facebook.com`, It always show the right information...

How is it possible to avoid this "`zero share`" result ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on error reporting to see the exact cause for this. Sometimes when you send too much of requests, your requests maybe blocked and your `file_get_contents` will return **FALSE**, in that case you will get a `0`

Try sending a non-existent value say `echo get_likes("1")` , You will get the result as 0. If you had turned on the error reporting you will get a warning too.

[`How do I enable error reporting in PHP?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1003917)

Comment: Thank you, here is the warning I got : Warning: file_get_contents(http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://facebook.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /homez.157/frenchpol/www/sharecounter.php on line 20
I read that I should use Curl instead of file_get_contents, but I don't manage to do something that works...

Comment: Yeah, thats what I am talking about.. Do you see 403 ? So seems like they have forbidden the access to your request and that's why you get a 0 as `file_get_contents` failed.